# Is this really what has to be done to clear the selection of an ASP.NET TreeView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `TreeView` called `myTreeView`. I want to be able to write a single statement after which `myTreeView.SelectedNode` is `null`, but `TreeView.SelectedNode` doesn't have a setter. I've looked at the decompiled source of `TreeView`, and there *is* a `SetSelectedNode` method (that can accept `null`), but it's `internal`.

So I made this extension method:

```
public static void ClearSelection(this TreeView treeView)
{
    var currentSelection = treeView.SelectedNode;
    if (currentSelection != null)
    {
        currentSelection.Selected = false;
    }
}
```

and now I can just say

```
myTreeView.ClearSelection();
```

But this seems insane. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no in-built method to do this. Your extension method looks great.

Even if `TreeView` did have an obscurely-named method to clear its selected node, I can only imagine it doing exactly the same as what you've written anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you havent already figured it out:

```
currentSelection.SelectedNode.Checked = false;
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I think you're confusing the `Checked` and `Selected` properties. If the `TreeView` has `ShowTextBoxes = true` then it will show a checkbox next to each node. These can be checked and unchecked, and you can retrieve checked nodes with the `CheckedNodes` property. However, when a node is clicked it becomes selected (provided it is not a navigation node). This is then the `SelectedNode` - irrespective of whether it has been checked.